How to Sign Out a User from Windows Service with Elevated Permissions Without Using psexec.exe?
I'm developing a Windows Service that needs to sign out a user from their session. However, I'm encountering an issue where the service does not have the necessary elevated permissions to log out the user on their behalf.
I understand that psexec.exe can be used to run commands with elevated privileges, which could help in signing out the user, but I would prefer not to rely on external tools like psexec.exe in my solution. Instead, I want to implement a function within my own code to achieve this.
I tried something using go but getting below error:
Failed to run command in user session: failed to query user token: A required privilege is not  held by the client.
Here are the specifics of my use case:

The service runs under a standard system account.
I need to sign out the user from their session programmatically.
The goal is to achieve this without integrating psexec.exe or similar external tools.

Is there a way to accomplish this using native Windows APIs or any other method within my code? If so, could you provide guidance or examples on how to implement such functionality?
Thank you!
package main

import (
"fmt"
"log"
"strings"
"syscall"
"unsafe"

"golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

const (
SE_DEBUG_NAME       = "SeDebugPrivilege"
SE_IMPERSONATE_NAME = "SeImpersonatePrivilege"
)

func main() {

// Attempt to get the SYSTEM token using specific SYSTEM processes
token, err := getSystemToken()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to get SYSTEM token: %v", err)
}
defer token.Close()

log.Println("Successfully obtained SYSTEM token", token)

// Ensure necessary privileges
if err := enablePrivilege(token, SE_DEBUG_NAME); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to enable SeDebugPrivilege: %v", err)
}

if err := enablePrivilege(token, SE_IMPERSONATE_NAME); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to enable SeImpersonatePrivilege: %v", err)
}

// Run a command as SYSTEM user, for example, open notepad
err = runCommandAsSystem(token, `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`, "/C", "start", "notepad.exe")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to run command as SYSTEM: %v", err)
}
}

func getSystemToken() (windows.Token, error) {
// Specific SYSTEM processes like winlogon.exe or lsass.exe
processes := []string{"winlogon.exe", "lsass.exe"}

for _, process := range processes {
    pid, err := findProcessByName(process)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to find process %s: %v", process, err)
        continue
    }

    hProcess, err := windows.OpenProcess(windows.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, false, pid)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to open system process (PID %d - %s): %v", pid, process, err)
        continue
    }
    defer windows.CloseHandle(hProcess)

    var systemToken windows.Token
    err = windows.OpenProcessToken(hProcess, windows.TOKEN_DUPLICATE|windows.TOKEN_QUERY|windows.TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY, &systemToken)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to get system token from process (PID %d - %s): %v", pid, process, err)
        continue
    }

    return systemToken, nil
}

return 0, fmt.Errorf("all attempts to retrieve SYSTEM token failed")
 }

func findProcessByName(name string) (uint32, error) {
snapshot, err := windows.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(windows.TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0)
if err != nil {
    return 0, fmt.Errorf("failed to create process snapshot: %v", err)
}
defer windows.CloseHandle(snapshot)

var entry windows.ProcessEntry32
entry.Size = uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(entry))

err = windows.Process32First(snapshot, &entry)
for err == nil {
    if syscall.UTF16ToString(entry.ExeFile[:]) == name {
        return entry.ProcessID, nil
    }
    err = windows.Process32Next(snapshot, &entry)
}

return 0, fmt.Errorf("process not found")
} 

func enablePrivilege(token windows.Token, privilegeName string) error {
var luid windows.LUID
privilegeNamePtr, err := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(privilegeName)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to convert privilege name to UTF-16: %v", err)
}

err = windows.LookupPrivilegeValue(nil, privilegeNamePtr, &luid)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to lookup privilege value: %v", err)
}

tokenPrivileges := windows.Tokenprivileges{
    PrivilegeCount: 1,
    Privileges: [1]windows.LUIDAndAttributes{
        {
            Luid:       luid,
            Attributes: windows.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED,
        },
    },
}

err = windows.AdjustTokenPrivileges(
    token,
    false,
    &tokenPrivileges,
    0,
    nil,
    nil,
)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to adjust token privileges: %v", err)
}
return nil
 }

func runCommandAsSystem(token windows.Token, command string, args ...string) error {
// Convert command and arguments to Windows UTF-16
cmdPtr, err := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(command)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

cmdLine := command + " " + strings.Join(args, " ")
cmdLinePtr, err := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(cmdLine)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

// Create the process in the SYSTEM account
startupInfo := new(windows.StartupInfo)
processInfo := new(windows.ProcessInformation)

err = windows.CreateProcessAsUser(
    token,
    cmdPtr,
    cmdLinePtr,
    nil,
    nil,
    false,
    0,
    nil,
    nil,
    startupInfo,
    processInfo,
)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer windows.CloseHandle(processInfo.Process)
defer windows.CloseHandle(processInfo.Thread)

log.Printf("Command executed with PID %d", processInfo.ProcessId)
return nil
 }

